# Minimax with alhpa-beta pruning for chess

Tags: python, chess, minimax

I am creating a chess AI using the minimax method with alpha-beta pruning. I am trying to understand how the alpha-beta pruning works but can't get my head around it when it comes to chess where you set a certain search depth.

How do minimax with alpha-beta solve sacrificing a piece for advantage 2-3 moves ahead? Won't it just look at the position at the sacrifice and immediately discard that branch as bad, therefore missing the good "sacrifice"?

Thank you for any clarifications or advice on improvements. Here is my code so far:

```py
def minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player):

    board.is_human_turn = not maximizing_player
    children = board.get_all_possible_moves()

    if depth == 0 or board.is_draw or board.is_check_mate:
        return None, evaluate(board)

    best_move = random.choice(children)

    if maximizing_player:
        max_eval = -math.inf
        for child in children:
            board_copy = copy.deepcopy(board)
            board_copy.move(child)
            current_eval = minimax(board_copy, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)[1]
            if current_eval > max_eval:
                max_eval = current_eval
                best_move = child
            alpha = max(alpha, current_eval)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return best_move, max_eval

    else:
        min_eval = math.inf
        for child in children:
            board_copy = copy.deepcopy(board)
            board_copy.move(child)
            current_eval = minimax(board_copy, depth - 1, alpha, beta, True)[1]
            if current_eval < min_eval:
                min_eval = current_eval
                best_move = child
            beta = min(beta, current_eval)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return best_move, min_eval
```

Comment: Chess AIs are hard to program. Anything based on 2-3 ply *will* suffer from a bad case of [horizon effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_effect) (the answer to your question "Won't it just look at the position at the sacrifice and immediately discard that branch as bad, therefore missing the good "sacrifice"?" is an emphatic "yes"). There are no simple solutions. You might have better luck asking this on [chess.se] (which has an active tag about chess engines).

Comment: Thanks John, will try that!

Answer (score 0):

To make this clear for you, I want to explain the minimax search tree.

In a minimax search tree, the engine assumes that in some certain depth ahead, both players do the best to maximize the board value (from `evaluate()`) at the end of the branch, which is after 3 moves. If the move sequence sacrifices a queen for nothing in 3 moves, this branch is considered bad. But if it sacrifices a queen for an inevitable checkmate in 2 moves, this is considered good.

By the way, Alpha-Beta pruning is the optimization of minimax, which help get the same result as minimax but faster. For more information, you may want to check out [Alpha-beta pruning on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning).

An easy way to make your engine look for more long term advantage is to increase the search depth, but as it usually comes with the time cost exploding exponentially, this is not quite feasible. Here are some suggestions to make your engine faster.

- Use **[Python chess library](https://pypi.org/project/chess/)**. I'm not sure if you are already using it from the code you've shown, but if not, I suggest you use this library. This library provides decent chess board calculation performance, convenient board representation, printing to FEN-string or PGN-string, and many more.
- Use **move ordering**. This can usually help find the good move faster, and you can make the move generation and sorting algorithm into a function, and use `functools.lru_cache()` to further improve the search speed. Notice that `lru_cache()` uses a hashtable to store previous executions, but `chess.Board` isn't hashable by default, so you need to put this after importing for the caching to work: `chess.Board.__hash__ = chess.polyglot.zobrist_hash`. For more information, check out [Move Ordering](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Move_Ordering).
- Using **opening data and opening searcher**. You can use data [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_of_Chess_Openings) to make your engine use openings, which takes no time to calculate, while also providing better results for the early game.